# Copy Range From One Sheet Paste Part of Range In another Sheet Based On Cell colorindex

Tags: excel, vba, range, background-color, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a range of cells on one worksheet and paste the color on another worksheet based on the colorindex.

I want to copy cells on sheet1

[image: img1]

and only paste cells with colorindex = 49 on sheet2

[image: img2]

This is what I've tried doing:
Is there a better or faster way of doing this than writing 90 If statements?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

If Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 49
Else: Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
End If

If Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = 49
Else: Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
End If

If Range("A3").Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Interior.ColorIndex = 49
Else: Range("A3").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
End If

If Range("A4").Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").Interior.ColorIndex = 49
Else: Range("A4").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
End If

If Range("A5").Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Interior.ColorIndex = 49
Else: Range("A5").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. To develop a good question that can allow us to help you, it might be helpful to read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question (or post a new one).

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
Function GetFillColor(Rng As Range) As Long
      GetFillColor = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Then you can use it in an if statement.  If getfillcolor(cell) = 49 then do something

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to copy the interior color over to the second sheet. If you want to specify another 'second' sheet that already exists you can put the sheet name like this instead `Sheets("Sheet Name").Interior ...`.

```
If sheets.count < 2 Then sheets.Add after:=sheets(1)

Dim theCell As Range
For Each theCell In sheets(1).Range("A1:E16")
    With theCell
        If .Interior.ColorIndex = 49 Then
            sheets(2).Cells(.row, .Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 49
        Else
            sheets(2).Cells(.row, .Column).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
        End If
    End With
Next theCell
```

Comment: This copys all the values to one row. It needs to correspond to the same cell